# Checking JSON object validity on POST method input in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem in an already realized project. Here I will give a simpler example to isolate the problem. Let's suppose we have a simple `Person` class.

```cs
namespace JsonTest.Models;

public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And we also have a simple controller with a single method whose job is to return JSON with `person` data.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using JsonTest.Models;

namespace JsonTest.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class JsonTestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SavePerson([FromBody] Person person)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { person.Id, person.FirstName, person.LastName, person.Age });
    }
}
```

This method behaves predictably with predictable data.

For example

```json
{
  "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "firstName": "David",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 26
}
```

will return

```json
{
  "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  "firstName": "David",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 26
}
```

But if you pass incomplete JSON (for some reason it happens sometimes in the project), the missing data will have default values.

For example

```json
{
  "firstName": "David",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 26
}
```

will return

```json
{
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "firstName": "David",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 26
}
```

But in my case the `person` object must be complete. Otherwise I expect an exception. I understand that I can put the `[BindRequired]` attribute on the Id property in the `Person` class, and replace `[FromBody]` with `[FromQuery]` in the method. But there are many such constructs in the project and I would like to solve this problem.

So, my question is **How to specify which data in a JSON object is required if the object is taken from the request body?**

*Edit*

I've already tried the `[Required]` attribute and validating the model with `ModelState.IsValid`. Doesn't help. `ModelState.IsValid` returns `true`.

*Edit 2*

The `person` object must have an explicitly specified identifier.

Comment: Assuming you haven't removed or customized the default features you get with a new ASP.NET project, you can put a `[Required]` attribute on the properties that are required.

Answer (score 1):

What your seeing is a [Null Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/isnullguid-function--guid-) `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` when the deserializer has no value.

If you change the `public Guid Id { get; set; }` to `public string Id { get; set; }` than it will work how *you* expect since a null string is nothing.

Comment: Yes, I realize that this is the default value for Guid. The problem is that, in fact, the body of the request contains a invalid object. Since in my case the person object must have an identifier that is explicitly specified. Even if it is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

Comment: And, again, what I expect is the exception. Because the request body cannot be serialized into an object if it doesn't have an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

> How to specify which data in a JSON object is required if the object
> is taken from the request body?

You can try the below code to check if  the Id is the nullGuid, then add Error  :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SavePerson([FromBody] Person person)
{
    if (person.Id ==  Guid.Empty)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Id", "Id is required.");
        return BadRequest(new ValidationProblemDetails(this.ModelState));
     
    }
    return new JsonResult(new { person.Id, person.FirstName, person.LastName, person.Age });
}
```

result:
[image]